# A piece of the code isn't working | no error message

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a calculator for basic algebraic equations. A part of my code isn't working is giving wrong answers. I am unsure exactly what the problem is, but I know it's after the `if Equation_Function == ("Subtraction")` line.

For a test question I am inputting the `280 - x = 287`, so the answer should be `-7`. I need the ending bit to test if the answer needs to be negative, but when it's there I get an answer of 7. When it is there I get no answer at all.

I expect an output of -7, but I don't get any answer at all. Instead I'm sent back to the "What type of function would you like to do?" question.

```
import sys
import math
import random

run = ("Yes")
while run == ("Yes"):
   Function = (input("What type of function would you like to do? >"))
   if Function == ("Equations"):
       x = (input("What is your first number? >"))
       y = (input("What is the answer to your equation? >"))
       Equation_Function = (input("What is the function in your equation? >"))
       if Equation_Function == ("Addition"):
           Variable = float(y) - float(x)
           print("The value of the variable is", Variable)
       if Equation_Function == ("Subtraction"):
           Variable = float(y) - float(x)
           if float(Variable) + float(x) != float(y):
               Variable = float(Variable) - float(Variable) - float(Variable)
               print("The value of the variable is", Variable)
           elif():
                print("The value of the variable is", Variable)
```

I have tried checking spelling and syntax as that is all I know how to do as well as checking any possible variable discrepancies.

Comment: What is `elif():` meant to do? Did you mean `else:`?

Comment: I tested and it looks like @MichaelButscher's suggestion fixed the issue.

Comment: im still not getting the correct answer to the equation 280-x=287 the answer is x=-7 which it should tell me instead it says 7

Comment: I figured it out I was cheaking for the wrong thing on line 15 I was doing 'if float(Variable) + float(x) != float(y)'        I needed to be doing     'if float(Variable) + float(y) != float(x)'

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if Equation_Function == ("Subtraction"):
           Variable =  float(x) - float(y)
```

Comment: im still not getting the correct answer to my sample equation   280-x=270  the answer being x = -7

Comment: @GreggMorgan This should be the correct answer. Your arithmetic operations are wrong. When you fix it with the equation above, you will still have to fix the following line as well because you're using an addition operation in the subtraction block.

Comment: To elaborate further: x - var = y. Therefore, var = x - y, which is what @WENWEN's answer is. You need not do further manipulations but just throw out the computed Variable as is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `elif()` with `else`. You can also just write "while true" but it's functionally the same. I think there are several edge cases you need to handle before this will actually work, but those are out of scope for this question.

```
import sys
import math
import random
while True:
   Function = (input("What type of function would you like to do? >"))
   if Function == ("Equations"):
       x = (input("What is your first number? >"))
       y = (input("What is the answer to your equation? >"))
       Equation_Function = (input("What is the function in your equation? >"))
       if Equation_Function == ("Addition"):
           Variable = float(y) - float(x)
           print("The value of the variable is", Variable)
       if Equation_Function == ("Subtraction"):
           Variable = float(x) - float(y)
           if float(Variable) + float(x) != float(y):
               Variable = float(Variable) - float(Variable) - float(Variable)
               print("The value of the variable is", Variable)
           else:
                print("The value of the variable is", Variable)
```

To specifically rewrite the code to pass your "280-x=287" test I edited to this:

```
import sys
import math
import random
while True:
   Function = (input("What type of function would you like to do? >"))
   if Function == ("Equations"):
       x = (input("What is your first number? >"))
       y = (input("What is the answer to your equation? >"))
       Equation_Function = (input("What is the function in your equation? >"))
       if Equation_Function == ("Addition"):
           Variable = float(y) - float(x)
           print("The value of the variable is", Variable)
       if Equation_Function == ("Subtraction"):
           Variable = float(x) + float(0 - float(y))
           print("The value of the variable is", Variable)
```

It passes the test but I still caution you that this is not a substitute for thoughtfully dealing with edge cases.

Comment: this didnt work still only getting 7 not the correct answer of -7

Comment: what do you mean @Charles Landau

Comment: @GreggMorgan I mean I edited my answer, the second code block passes the `280-x=287` test with -7

Comment: im sorry I didnt see the second block of code as I had thought of the problem and therfore the solution before hand(just so happened to be like right after I posted this :| ) this does work though congrates. @Charles Landau

Comment: @GreggMorgan if you have arrived at the solution you should A) mark this or one of the other answers as the correct answer or B) answer your own question and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I do not believe that either of the answers provided gave me the solution I found myself shortly after so I did not do so